# How to store multiple character values in a single integer variable?

Tags: c

How to store multiple character values in a single integer variable?
For example, I have four characters with values a = 45; b = A9; c = 44 and d = 55. I need to store all of them in a single integer variable which looks like `l = 0x45A94455`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift and or bitwise operations. each char is 1 byte the int is 4.

So

`unsigned int i = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d;`

Then if you want to print it in hex.

`printf("0x%08X", i)`

`%08X` means padded to 8 characters with 0's `08` print in hex form using capital letters `X` (`x` is lowercase).